# Why did fuzzy logic fall out of fashion?

Tags: machine-learning, fuzzy-logic

[Fuzzy logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic) seemed like an active area of research in machine learning and data mining back when I was in grad school (early 2000s). Fuzzy inference systems, fuzzy c-means, fuzzy versions of the various neural network and support vector machine architectures were all being taught in grad courses and discussed in conferences.

Since I've started paying attention to ML again (~2013), Fuzzy Logic seems to have dropped off the map completely and its absence from the current ML landscape is conspicuous given all the AI hype.

Was this a case of a topic simply falling out of fashion, or was there a specific limitation of fuzzy logic and fuzzy inference that led to the topic being abandoned by researchers?